# Finding magnification of microscope from focal lengths

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

How do you find the magnification of a microscope given the focal lengths of the objective and eyepiece? What else can you find given this information? If finding the magnification is not feasible with just the focal lengths, what other information do you need?